# Why do I get un-queued while levelling?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am currently in the process of finishing levelling one of each class before the start of the next expansion through a combination of questing and completing battlegrounds.

At the lower levels it is only taking me 10-15 minutes to complete each level and move onto the next one, however, I have noticed that I get removed from the queue for battlegrounds each time I level.

Why would this be?

Comment: I do not have any sources, but it is a known bug. My whole guild complains about it while we are leveling alts (especially when a tank levels and the leader doesn't realize it to back out of the queue for them). I can say from my experience since 5.0.4, it is a bug that I've had to deal with while leveling two accounts.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug because battlegrounds have level tiers i.e. you can enter a battleground with people in levels similar to yours. If you queue to a battleground in level 12 you queue with other player in the tier 10-19 or something and if you level up then you may change tier. So I do not know if the game prevents you from queueing in a different tier on level up and you must requeue manually so the server adjust your queue to the new level you got.

Comment: My comment to pixel was referring to also being in those tiers (i.e. 10 - 19 tier, I level from 12 to 13, then get kicked out of the queue). This also happens during dungeon finder as well.

Comment: In [patch 4.0.3](http://www.wowwiki.com/Patch_4.0.3), the battle ground system was split up into 5 level brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an intended feature to keep higher levels out of lower level brackets.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: No, but it's pretty logical from a design perspective. Not many people want level 55's in the 50-54 bracket.